# How do I make this website recognise my arrays as part of a valid url query?

Tags: python, urllib

EDIT:
In a similar vein, when I now try to log into their account with a post request, what is returned is none of the errors they suggest on their site, but is in fact a "JSON exception". Is there any way to debug this, or is an error code 500 completely impossible to deal with?

I'm well aware this question has been asked before. Sadly, when trying the proposed answers, none worked. I have an extremely simple Python project with urllib, and I've never done web programming in Python before, nor am I even a regular Python user. My friend needs to get access to content from [this site](https://mangadex.org), but their user-friendly front-end is down and I learned that [they have a public API to access their content](https://api.mangadex.org/docs.html). Not knowing what I'm doing, but glad to try to help and interested in the challenge, I have very slowly set out.

Note that it is necessary for me to only use standard Python libraries, so that any finished project could easily be emailed to their computer and just work.

The following works completely fine minus the "originalLanguage" query, but when using it, which the API has documented as an array value, no matter whether I comma-separate things, or write "originalLanguage[0]" or "originalLanguage0" or anything that I've seen online, this creates the error message from the server: "Array value expected but string detected" or something along those lines.

Is there *any* way for me to get this working? Because it clearly can work, otherwise the API wouldn't document it. Many thanks.

In case it helps, when using "[]" or "<>" or "{}" or any delimeter I could think of, my IDE didn't recognise it as part of the URL.

```py
import urllib.request as request
import urllib.parse as parse


def make_query(url, params):
    url += "?"

    for i in range(len(params)):
        url += list(params)[i]
        url += '='
        url += list(params.values())[i]

        if i < len(params) - 1:
            url += '&'

    return url


base = "https://api.mangadex.org/manga"
params = {
    "limit": "50",
    "originalLanguage": "en"
}

url = make_query(base, params)

req = request.Request(url)
response = request.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: FYI look up `urllib.parse.urlencode` in the Python documentation  to do the creation of the string of parameters - all you do is add the ? At the front.

Comment: if I was you I'd use the `requests` module where you can just pass the params dict directly whe nperforming the request https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: @DevLounge I’m sure you’re right, and it certainly is very pythonic to use module after module, but my project needs to work without third party installs in order to be accessible to my friend